# tin-can audio (meaning)

Tags: meaning

Example:

> The Internet's bandwidth is growing at rates unimagined only a few years ago. The move toward cable and DSL as the connections of choice to the Net means that the Internet is losing a reputation for jerky, small video and **tin-can audio**. The tricks used today to overcome the narrow bandwidth of traditional modems, described in this chapter, will soon be only of historical interest. If your home doesn't yet have multiple PCs, it probably will eventually, and at least one of them is destined to become your television, radio, stereo, and telephone-it'll blend into one universal source of information and communication.

How do you understand that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This refers to the [tin can telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_can_telephone), two tin cans with a wire between them.

[image]

<sub>image taken from hyraxllc.com</sub>

When speaking in one of the cans, you can hear the voice when listening to the other can, but in a very low quality. So 'tin can audio' means audio of low quality.